# How can I append a structure entry and set its order?

Tags: plugin-development, structure, relations

I'd like to attach children to a specific Structure entry in a specific order...

> - Entry A
> - Entry B
>
>   - *Imported Entry 2*
>   - *Imported Entry 1*
>   - *Imported Entry 3*
> - Entry C

I've got a `$records` array to turn into imported entries:

```
array(
    'name'      => 'Whatever',
    'updated_at' => '2014-02-27T04:14:29Z',
    'position'   => 1, // int representing the sort order
    [...]
)
```

<strike>As I'm looping through my array to create new Craft Structure Entries, I need to be able to define the parent (Entry B), I'm just not sure how.</strike> I've [figured out how](https://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/controllers/EntriesController#actionSaveEntry-detail) to attach new children to *Entry B*, I just don't know how to programmatically set their order. My imagination writes code that looks like this:

```
$parentCriteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);

$parentCriteria->search  = 'slug:entry-b';
$parentCriteria->section = 'sectionName';
$parentCriteria->type    = 'sectionType';

$entries = $parentCriteria->find();
$parent = $entries[0];

foreach ($records as $row)
{
    $entry = new EntryModel();

    $entry->sectionId = 4;
    $entry->typeId    = 4;
    $entry->parentId  = $parent->id;
    $entry->authorId  = 1;
    $entry->postDate  = $row->updated_at;
    $entry->title     = $row->name;
    $entry->sortOrder = $row->position; // ← quite impossible!

    $success = craft()->entries->saveEntry($entry);
}
```

It's `$entry->sortOrder` that's completely made up—**how do you attach an entry to a specific parent in a specific order?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're adding them all as new entries anyway, **why not just sort the records before you create the entries?**

```
usort($records, array($this, 'sortCategoriesByPosition'));
```

Add that before your `foreach` loop, then...

```
private function sortCategoriesByPosition($a, $b)
{
    if ($a->position == $b->position)
        return 0; 

    return ($a->position < $b->position) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Stop trying to make things harder than they should be.